DPDK: Can we create multiple RSS flows with unique set of queues for different patterns?
I have 40 RX queues setup and I need to create multiple RSS flows.
For e.g.
Flow 1: Match a particular IP pattern and distribute it to specified RX queues set (0 - 29)
Flow 2: Match a particular IP pattern and distribute it to specified RX queues set (30 - 39)
uint16_t queue_indices[] = {0,...29};
uint16_t queue_indices2[] = {30,..39};

action_rss1 = (struct rte_flow_action_rss){
                    .types = rss_conf.rss_hf,
                    .key_len = rss_conf.rss_key_len,
                    .queue_num = 30,
                    .key = rss_key,
                    .queue = queue_indices,
            };

action_rss2 = (struct rte_flow_action_rss){
                    .types = rss_conf.rss_hf,
                    .key_len = rss_conf.rss_key_len,
                    .queue_num = 10,
                    .key = rss_key,
                    .queue = queue_indices2,
            };

struct rte_flow_item pattern[] = {
                [0]={
                        .type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ETH,

                },
                [1]={
                        .type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_IPV4,
                        .spec = &ipv4_spec,
                        .mask = &ipv4_mask,
                       

                },
                [2]={
                        .type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_UDP,
                },

                [3]={
                        .type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_END,
                }
        };
        struct rte_flow_item pattern2[] = {
                [0]={
                        .type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ETH,

                },
               
                [1]={
                        .type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_IPV4,
                        .spec = &ipv4_spec2,
                        .mask = &ipv4_mask2,
                        

                },
                [2]={
                        .type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_UDP,
                },

                [3]={
                        .type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_END,
                }
        };
rte_flow_validate(bond_port, &attr, pattern, action_rss1, &error);
rte_flow_create(bond_port, &attr, pattern, action_rss1, &error);

rte_flow_validate(bond_port, &attr, pattern2, action_rss2, &error);
rte_flow_create(bond_port, &attr, pattern2, action_rss2, &error);



Also is it possible to use symmetric hash and ETH_RSS_L3_SRC_ONLY | ETH_RSS_L3_DST_ONLY
